# How can I store a word that's typed into an input as the whole word, rather than the word being stored as it's being typed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a beginner project that has a feature where you can create a dictionary of words that you put in yourself. For this feature I created a reusable input component that you type the word you want to be in the dictionary into. This input dynamically stores the word onto an array that will later be use to create the dictionary in the store.

The problem I'm getting is that when I type into the input the word is stored as it's being typed, rather than storing the whole word, which is how I would like it to be stored.

For example if I type in the word cat it would be stored as
`words: ["c" , "ca", "cat"]`
rather than
`words: ["cat"]`

This is the function i'm using

```
onWordChange = (e) => {
    const word = e.target.value
    
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      words: prevState.words.concat(`${word}`)
    }))
```

Comment: Rather than constantly updating the word as the user types, have a save button that updates the array of words.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `onChange` event from the input, there's nothing much you can do, other than adding a "delayed effect" to add the word after x milliseconds.

A second option would be to use `onBlur` to trigger the words update, but then you need to blur the input field.

I would go as suggested by Jared, either adding a button to update the array, or triggering the update when Enter is pressed, or both, combining it with a form.

Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-volhard-pq3t1?file=/src/App.js